# How to install VPNPPTP?

Tags: installation, vpn

In manual it seems obvious but I don't understand how to run this application.

The full name of file is `vpnpptp_setup-en-Linux-x86_64-Install.tar.gz`
Inside the archive it has ready to run application. [Link to application.](http://code.google.com/p/vpnpptp/)

So, how to install vpnpptp on Ubuntu 11.04? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple but not simple for user with windows background. I've tried to install application which was on flash drive, the system didn't allow me to run it without any notification.

Answer (score 0):

That application has a package for Debian and Ubuntu. Just scroll down the downloads list until you see "vpnpptp-allde-0.3.3-i386.deb". If you have a 64 bit installation, you will have to download "vpnpptp-allde-0.3.3-amd64.deb". Just click on the package and Ubuntu Software Centre will pop up. Click "Install" to install it.

Comment: I've tried to use network manager and failed. Maybe it's because my ISP requires L2TP IPsec VPN type.

Comment: @megas Oh, then try downloading the debian package from the site.